# Can't get rid of old folder in application bundle

Tags: ios, xamarin

Seems to be similar to this question:

[Xcode won't let go a resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629747/xcode-wont-let-go-a-resource-file)

But for Xamarin. I have a xamarin solution I'm working on in Visual Studio for iOS. I added some resources in one place and then later decided to move them somewhere else. But when I build the project and look at the application bundle on our build Mac the originals are still there. Even though I scrubbed every instance of them from my Windows machine it somehow still ending up in the application bundle!

How do I complete scrub any cached traces? I've reset the simulator, cleaned and rebuilt from visual studio, even deleted the `bin` and `obj` but I can't get rid of the damn things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem with files I've deleted from VS still being included in the bundle when running the app.

I followed the output from The Mac Server log and you can see from there where the files are being copied from, in my case

/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/[App_Name]

Delete your application folder in that cache and it will fix the issues.

Comment: I think you meant ${HOME}/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/

Comment: It was under the home directory for me as well. Also if you're a Mac noob like me note that the `~/Library` folder is hidden by default so you'll have to either [make Finder show all folders](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57607/how-can-i-view-the-root-directory-along-with-all-its-subdirectories-in-finder) or simply paste the path into the "Go to folder" dialog.