# PhoneGap build does not look correct (e.g. missing project icons)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, ipa

I have a simple, [open source project](https://github.com/ray023/FindAFit/tree/attempt-with-code) I want to put in the App Store.

In the Application Loader, I get three errors about icons not being in the right place:

[image]

The project contains the icons and the config.xml references them:

[image]

However, if I take the IPA file from phonegap build and extract it, the /www/res folder disappears:

[image]

The hash from my github project matches My PhoneGap Build project hash:
[image]

What could be the reasons the icons are not being added to the IPA?

Also, the root folder of the ipa contains the following pngs:

- icon-60.png
- icon-60@2x.png
- icon-60@3x.png
- icon-76.png
- icon-76@2x.png
- Default~iphone.png

these are all empty, transparent png files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem and was able to successfully submit binary by:

- copying my open source project to a new folder,
- moving config.xml and icon.png to the www folder
- zipping that folder
- creating a new, private app on build.phonegap.com
- uploading the zip file to the new app

It wa my first attempt at getting an app in the stores. The learning curve was my biggest hurdle. Oddly, I did not have this problem the first time I submitted my binary to the App store.

It was only after subsequent builds last week that it showed up. It was also posted to Google Play and the Windows Store before; and worked.

Shrugging my shoulders on that one because I don't understand how it could successfully submit two weeks before but not last week.

Answer (score 0):

Inside **config.xml** you have to define the path of icons for each paltform.

For example, what I have done.

- Inside the **img** folder I have **iosIcons** folder that contains all iOS specific icons
- Inside **img**, I have another folder **androidIcons** to hold Android related icons

After that modify the **config.xml** and add below details:

**iOS**

```
<!-- Icons for IOS -->
    <icon gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" src="img/iosIcons/icon-57.png"  />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" src="img/iosIcons/icon-72.png"  />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="114" src="img/iosIcons/icon-57-2x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" src="img/iosIcons/icon-72-2x.png"  /> 

<!-- Splash for IOS --> 
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" src="img/splash.png"/>  
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" src="img/splash@2x.png"/>   
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" src="images/phone/1x/bglangscreen.png" />
```

**Android**

```
<!-- Icons for Andriod -->
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="img/androidIcons/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="img/androidIcons/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="img/androidIcons/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="img/androidIcons/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />

<!-- Splash for Andriod --> 
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android"  src="images/phone/1x/bglangscreen.png" />
```

**Update:**

If issue still persist then its **XCode compile issue.**

- **Clean the project and re-build the App**

and read these answers on similar issues [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629747/xcode-wont-let-go-a-resource-file), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316501/xcode-5-invalid-image-path-cfbundleicons) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627697/problem-with-icon-png-icon-specified-in-the-info-plist-not-found-under-the-top).